# JavaScript method to accept 1 to 99 number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on an application where I want to validate user. I just want to accept number from `1` to `99` also need to avoid `0` at the start. I really tried hard but didn't find any solution.

Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.

```
<input
  max='99'
  min='1'
  type='number'
  placeholder='Enter Approved Discount'
  className='textInput'
  onChange={(e) => {
    finalPriceFunc(e.target.value, paymentPlan);
    setCondition({ ...checkCondition, showFinalPrice: true });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Resolve *what* issue? What exactly is the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: what is not working in your actual html? It is fine for what you are looking for. Only, I'd advice to remove inline javascript

Comment: @Pointy Actually I want to achieve to accept number between 1 to 99

Comment: @LelioFaieta This looks more like jsx not html

Comment: remove inline javascript, everything is seems ok..

Comment: @bergi yep! I realized after posting the comment. Thanks for pointing out :-)

Comment: Yes , I am using React

Comment: OK, well in what way does the code fail? Does *anything* happen? Are there errors?

Answer (score 0):

Input Min & Max properties work on Form inside after submitting form.
But if you want check onfly use this

Javascript:

```
          <input
              max="99"
              min="1"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter Approved Discount"
              className="textInput"
              onChange={(e) => {
                console.log(e);
                let v = parseInt(e.target.value);
                if (v < 1) e.target.value = 1;
                if (v > 99) e.target.value = 99;
              }}
            />
```

in React you need use `setState` instead of `e.target.value`

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-spence-1qb7f)

Comment: "*In React you need use setState instead of e.target.value*" - not if the input value is uncontrolled

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sanitizeDiscountValue(elmNode) {
  console.log(elmNode.value);

  let value = parseInt(elmNode.value, 10);
  value = Math.abs(Number.isFinite(value) ? value : 1);

  elmNode.value = Math.min(Math.max(value, 1), 99);

  console.log(elmNode.value);
}
function handleDiscountChange(evt) {

  const value = sanitizeDiscountValue(evt.target);

  // finalPriceFunc(value, paymentPlan);
  // setCondition({ ...checkCondition, showFinalPrice: true });
}

function ApprovedDiscount() {
  return (
    <input
      max="99"
      min="1"
      type="number"
      placeholder="Enter Approved Discount"
      className='textInput'
      onChange={ handleDiscountChange }
    />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<ApprovedDiscount/>, document.querySelector("#react-root"));
```

```css
.textInput[type="number"] {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: @ReactGuy ... are there any questions left about the sanitizing approach?